# What is a Spark-idiomatic way to efficiently process a stream with lots of redundant but confirmed overlapping segments of data?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm new to Spark and am attempting to learn and use the new Structured Streaming approach in particular.  I'm sure I can find a hacky way to do the following, but am looking to understand the "canonical" way to do such a task.

Suppose I have an underlying data source D, that is merely an infinite stream of values.  I don't get to see D; instead I get to see a derived stream D', a sequence of windows of the data in D.  Each window is essentially a "left" and "right" offset into D, guaranteeing:

1. the left offsets are monotonically increasing
2. the right offsets are monotonically increasing
3. every element in D is seen in at least one window in D'.

For instance, as a contrived example, suppose D was a source of alphanumeric chars:

```
OFFSET | VALUE
    01 | A
    02 | X 
    03 | Q 
    04 | W
    05 | 1
    06 | I
    07 | 8
    08 | 2
    09 | 7
    10 | X
    11 | T
    ....
```

D' might look like:

```
(1, 2, "AX")
(1, 4, "AXQW")
(1, 7, "AXQW1I8")
(6, 9, "I827")
(6,11, "I827XT")
...
```

Critically; I'm guaranteed to see everything in D at least once, but I'm going to see most things a ton of times.  (In the actual underlying real-world problem, there are several such D streams, and gigabytes of data.)

In the cloud, I do not have access to D, but only this derived stream D' of emissions of overlapping chunks (the two offset numbers and the data that was between them).

What is an efficient and idiomatic way to process only the unique data seen so far from D Exactly Once, given D'?

(Previously, in Apache Storm, I used a Bolt with an in-memory cache backed by the database to keep track of "max seen", and just cut parts of each emission that were beneath the max, while also updating "max seen."  The result would be a derived stream e.g.:

```
AX
QW
1I8
27
XT
...
```

However, I don't see many examples of Spark Workers/Executors needing to access an API or underlying database to operate on their data or maintain some sort of global state like a "max seen", and suspect it's problematic?)